# JavaScript toggle code works in J4 but not in J3

Tags: joomla-3.x, javascript

I have some simple code that hides or shows a div (that will contain an embedded contact form) when a button is clicked.

I first set it up in J4.0.3 and it works fine, but when I tried in J3.10.2 the code 'selector' is not recognised.

Here is the code (which you can also see at [codepen.io][1]

In J3 the 'selector' at the end of the second line is not highlighted in blue in the editor as it is in the first line and as the other elements - 'test', 'tests', etc are.

```
for (const selector of [".toggle-form"]) {
    const tests = [...document.querySelectorAll(selector)];
    for (const test of tests) {
        test.addEventListener('click', () => {
            tests.filter(f => f !== test).forEach(f => {
            f.classList.remove('form-opened');
            f.setAttribute("aria-expanded", "false");
            });
        test.classList.toggle('form-opened');
        let ariaExpanded = test.classList.contains('form-opened').toString();
        test.setAttribute("aria-expanded", ariaExpanded);
        })
    }
}
```

Can anyone explain this and tell me what I need to do to make it work in J3x? Thanks.

EDIT: two screenshots showing Firefox inspector and debugger tabs

[![Firefox inspector tab][2]][2]

[![Firefox debugger tab][3]][3]

[1]: https://codepen.io/Scrabble96/pen/NWvWwOY)
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mtPF0.jpg
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WVfZL.jpg

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why it would be working in J4, but not J3. That said, you're unecessarily using nested `for` loops, rather than a single `forEach` iterator.

You can use the following:

```
// Create an array using Array.from(), so that we can filter later on
const toggles = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.toggle-form'));

// Iterate over the array
toggles.forEach((toggle) => {
    toggle.addEventListener('click', () => {
      toggles
        .filter((f) => f !== toggle)
        .forEach((f) => {
          f.classList.remove('form-opened');
          f.setAttribute('aria-expanded', false);
        });
      toggle.setAttribute('aria-expanded', toggle.classList.contains('form-opened'));
      toggle.classList.toggle('form-opened');
    });
});
```

You might find this will also work on your J3 instance

Comment: Unfortunately, it still doesn't work. In the Joomla code editor the first `toggles` in the first line is blue, as are all instances of `toggle` and `f`, but all the other `toggles` are black text. I'd upload an image if I could. This is in a two-day-old installation of Protostar with no extra extensions or plugins.

Comment: What editor are you using? Have you tried using CodeMirror instead?

Comment: I am using the default Joomla 3.10x admin editor: CodeMirror - I have not changed anything in the installation

Comment: So when you save the content, and view the front-end of your site, are you getting any errors in your browser console?

Comment: Sorry so long replying. Error reporting is on maximum and there are no errors at all on the front-end.

Comment: Not PHP errors, I mean in your browser console

Comment: I've added two screenshots to the original post, showing FF inspector and debugger tabs. No errors. On the Console tab there's just a long list of cross-site cookie notices.

Comment: Actually, on the Console tab, it's the same cross-site cookie conflict on all files, e.g.: Cookie “e3d6310e22ed2e4a1d304ae57fc6f9a6” will be soon treated as cross-site cookie against “https://protostar.[my_domain]/templates/protostar/js/template.js?063de4d5de44ead786ad85b16ac19c42” because the scheme does not match.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, by looking at other scripts on other J3 sites, I find that I have to wrap the code like this and it works:

```
window.onload=function() {
// original code as above
}
```

(although I still have the cross-site cookie notices, but I think that's another issue...)